# lvalue required as unary '&' operand error in C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to pass by reference a value to another pointer, however I am getting the error: lvalue required as unary '&' operand.

The following are my attempts:

```
Node<Item,Key> *root;

Node<Item, Key> *x= root;

x= &x->getLeft(); // it does not let me use &
```

The following is my getter for getLeft():

```
template<typename Item, typename Key>
Node<Item, Key>* Node<Item, Key>::getLeft() {

    return left;
}
```

I appreciate if someone could identify my mistake.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The mistake is easy enough to spot, but what's baffling is *why* you made the mistake. So please tell, what did you think the `&` was for?

Comment: I agree with @KerrekSB: please do tell why.

Answer (score 4):

You mean:

```
x = x->getLeft();
```

The return value of `getLeft()` is already a pointer.

Comment: Then, should I change the return statement of my getter in order to be able to use: x= &x->getLeft(); ?

Comment: @user3136756: *why* do you want the `&` in there?

Comment: @user3136756: No, please stop guessing. Just make this one change, and all will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

`x->getLeft()` returns a `Node<Item, Key>*` - it's already a pointer. If you take the address of it, you'd get a `Node<Item, Key>**`, which is not something you can assign to `x`.

You appear to another problem though. Your `root` pointer is uninitialized. Then you're copying it over to `x` and trying to access a member by indirection (`->`). You're going to need to make `root` and `x` point at something before you do that.